# Two ways about loading JS library 

Tags: jquery, javascript

I saw someone load JS in his html  as following (via JQuery ajax):

(jquery.utils.js, jquery.utils.js, browser_files/background.js in the same domain)

```
<script>

var scriptsArr = [
"scripts/jquery.utils.js",
"scripts/jquery.utils.js",
"browser_files/background.js",
]

for(var i=0;i<scriptsArr.length;i++)
{
    var path = scriptsArr[i];

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: chrome.extension.getURL(path),
        type: "GET",
        success: function(){},
        dataType: 'script'
    });
}
</script>
```

This approach(via ajax) has some advantages??

And why use tag

```
<script src="">
```

attribute "src" load this library????

Comment: This looks like code from a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Lazy Loading or On-demand loading of JavaScript.

Apart from saving unnecessary loading of script files the other main advantages is speed.

Scripts loaded asynchronously are non-blocking. i.e. they do not interrupt the loading of a page.

Comment: No..  As I said before, putting scripts in the head tag manually would execute those scripts during page-load in the sequence that they appear i.e. "synchronously".

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax concept improve the fast page rendering.Better use script tags at the bottom for the best performance.

Comment: Thanks, but put script tag at bottom, some page use JS or ajax control  some content can't display correctly and immediately for user.